# {{ TWIG }} Define Dynamic Array Name

Tags: arrays, twig

I am using {{TWIG}} with the Shopwired Platform.  Hard coded into one of the templates is a gallery;

```
{# Render carousel #}
{% set gallery_name = 'global.theme.settings.gallery_location %}
```

This of course is working and great, however I would like to extend upon this and make some dynamic galleries for the site I am building.

I have figured out how to append/prepend the page title to build this;

```
{# Render carousel #}
{% set gallery_name = 'global.theme.settings.gallery_' ~ title|lower %}
{% set images = gallery_name %}
```

When I use {{ images }} to echo the result, it outputs the string name 'global.theme.settings.gallery_location' (which is correct for the page I am on) and not 'Array' as expected and desired.

The following, must be nearly right, but it only outputs one item from the array..

```
{# Render carousel #}
{% set gallery_name = 'global.theme.settings.gallery_' ~ title|lower %}
{% set images = [gallery_name] %}
```

I'm close.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) to accomplish this

Comment: Any chance you could expand on this? I am new to TWIG and actually did try a couple of things with attribute, but didn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 0):

To use dynamic keys, u can't relate on the `dot` notation to acces properties as the compiler can't handle that. Either use `attribute` or the `array` notation to access the data.

```
{% set arr = {
     foo : {
         bar : {
             foobar : {
                 dynamic_index : 42,
             }
         }
     }
} %}

{% set key = 'dynamic' %}

{{ attribute(arr['foo']['bar']['foobar'], key~'_index') }} {# 42 #}

{{ arr['foo']['bar']['foobar'][key~'_index'] }} {# 42 #}
```